# How to select data from gridview to form in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have to insert data into 'production' table. The productid, productname, batchno is stored in  a table 'productbatch'. I want to select these fields from gridview to the form on clicking on the gridview. How can I do that?
index.php of producbatch -

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\production\models\ProductbatchSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Productbatches';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="productbatch-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Productbatch', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            //['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
            'itemid',
            'productname',
            'batchno:ntext',
            //'mfgdate',
            //'expdate',
            // 'mrp',
            // 'rate',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

</div>
```

_form of production

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\web\View;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\production\models\Production */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="production-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productiondate')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'itemid')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productname')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'batchno')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'prodqty')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
<?php
    $this->RegisterJs ( "
    $('document').ready(function(){
        // $('#".Html::getInputId($model, 'mrp')."').keyup(function(){ 
        //              var total = this.value;
        //              var percent = 10;
        //              var discount_value = this.value - ((total / 100) * percent);
        //             $('#".Html::getInputId($model, 'rate')."').val(discount_value);    
        //          });
         var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
    });

    ", View::POS_END);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is base on check columns and obtaining the reldated rows in an array

this is from yii guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#checkbox-column

```
    echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'id' => 'my_gridview_id',
        'columns' => [
            // ...
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
            // you may configure additional properties here
        ],
    ],
```

Users may click on the checkboxes to select rows of the grid. The selected rows may be obtained by calling the following JavaScript

```
     var keys = $('#my_gridview_id').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, I've added the index.php of productbatch and _form of production in the question. Please tell me how I can access productbatch gridview with checkbox from production form.

Comment: When I'm opening the production/create  - it is simply opening a form with fields - productiondate, itemid, productname,batchno and qty. Now I want to fillup itemid, productname,batchno from the checkboxcolumn from productbatch. Not getting how can I select the data from productbatch checkboxcolumn when I'm in the Create Production form.

Comment: You can add a button (or a column with a button) and inside this button call the javascript you need ..

Comment: I'm not so sure how to do this. Can you please tell me.

Comment: there are many sample ion google for calling a javscript function by a button

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, now I can redirect from production form to productbatch gridview which have checkbox in it. Also I've added a button in the productbatch index file with code - <?=  Html::button("(+)",array('title'=>"Topic",'onclick'=>'js:selectproductforproduction();')); ?>
And I've created selectproductforproduction.js file in frontenend/web/js folder which have code - function selectproductforproduction() {    
    var keys = $('#my_gridview_id').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');    
}
selectproductforproduction();
I've stuck here. Nothing happens when I click on the button. Please help

Comment: Or Can we add a button in the actioncolumn in productbatch gridview which can pass the row data to the production form?